# Can I use a DD command in a init.d startup script in ubuntu core 16?

Tags: scripts, backup, ubuntu-core, dd

Can I use a DD command in a init.d startup script in ubuntu core 16?

I want to create a script that will automate the restoring of a backup image using DD command in a live ubuntu core environment, mkdir command is working in my custom script in init.d but dd command is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: If the command is not being found you can prefix with directory name, ie: `/bin/dd`. Use `type -a dd` to find the exact directory name.

Comment: @muru 

the backup image is not being written automatically, and all the commands after the DD command won't work. in the sample script provided, helloworld directory will be created but not helloworld2. 
Sample Script: https://shrib.com/#VELnaTGHmO4evbJGLma6